# Kreait Firebase Exception Invalid Argument Exception The path of a URI with an authority must start with a slash "/" or be empty in laravel8

Tags: laravel-8

I need support in this error:

> ```
> KreaitFirebaseExceptionInvalidArgumentException The path of a URI with an authority must start with a slash "/" or be empty in laravel8
>
> FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS="laravel-firebase-d24ae-firebase-adminsdk-weket-8dab0df6fb.json"
>
> FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="https://laravel-firebase-d24ae-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.